# Solving general distribution for mean and standard deviation

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Given the question:

> The weights of cats are normally distributed. It is known that 10% of cats weigh more than 1.8 kg, and 15% of cats weigh less than 1.35 kg. Find the mean and the standard deviation of this distribution.

How is the answer of $\mu=1.55$ and $\sigma=0.194$ derived?

---

I have only been able to simplify to:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Pr(X>1.8) &= 0.1 \\
\Pr(X<1.35) &= 0.15
\end{aligned}
$$

Where $X$ is the normally distributed random variable

Comment: Hint: use your empirical rule estimates - how much data is within one standard deviation of the mean, ...?

Comment: @SeanRoberson 66.7%?